What is the standard threshold value that is best for accuracy when employing Euclidean distance as a metric for gauging textual similarity?
I'm using Euclidean distance as a metric to compare two sentences for similarity while clustering them using my custom incremental KMeans algorithm. The current threshold value I'm using is 0.7 which seems to work well in the data which I have. I'm just wondering if there is a standard threshold value which will work optimally in all the cases?
I want to know if there is a standard threshold value for Euclidean distance or there isn't one.
